# Mongoose OR operator with _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose.

When I do this, it works fine:

```
userModel.find({  $or:[
                        {first_name:"Bob"}, 
                        {last_name: "Marley"}
                      ] 
               }, function(err, result){
                 if(err) //do something;

                 console.log(result);
               });
```

But when I use _id as one of the expressions, it only looks for the _id and doesn't care about the other expressions:

```
userModel.find({  $or:[
                        {_id: "56b426aa1d6c7a642ab1a52d"}, 
                        {last_name: "Marley"}
                      ] 
               }, function(err, result){
                 if(err) //do something;

                 console.log(result);
               });
```

Recap:
The first example would either find first name Bob or last name Marley.
But the second example would only find either that exact id that I provided or null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a document sample that proves this? Also turn on debugging and look at how mongoose is sending the statement `mongoose.set("Debug",true)`

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice it produced an error. 
The error was cast to an ObjectId failed. I had added a character to the value of _id and it made the ObjectId invalid.
Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The MongoDB `_id` field is a special type of field and needs to be initialised as follows, before it can be used in the query:

```
new Mongoose.Types.ObjectId("56b426aa1d6c7a642ab1a52d")
```

or

```
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;
new ObjectId("56b426aa1d6c7a642ab1a52d");
```